# Can I use my NAS as a bridge between Modem and Router?

Tags: networking, freebsd, bridge

My current home network setup is this:

```
ISP <-> Modem <-> Router(with NAT)/Wireless AP <-> Home Network
```

My NAS is on the home network. I'm using FreeNAS, an OS based on FreeBSD. I have 5 ethernet ports in the machine. FreeNAS let's you use your NICs as bridges. I don't know much about how this works.

Bridging is often compared to a switch, which you cannot put between a modem and router. However, I believe bridging can also be used similarly to a hub. Could I use this to monitor network traffic between my modem and router?

In essence, can I use my NAS as a bridge like below to monitor network traffic?

```
ISP <-> Modem <-> NAS (as bridge) <-> Router(with NAT)/Wireless AP <-> Home Network
```

I don't think what I want to do is possible, but I just wanted to check with some knowledgeable people before dismissing it.

I am aware that you can set up a machine to act as a router using pfsense. I think the setup I describe above is also similar to a DMZ? Is that true?

Comment: Don't forget that you'll still need to connect the NAS device to the home network. I'm not familiar with FreeNAS, but if it has tools to allow you to snoop on bridged traffic and allows you to pick just two interfaces to bridge without an IP address on the bridge, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible, but I'm certainly not convinced it's wise.

FreeNAS being based on FreeBSD, has full ability to use the `pf` firewall/routing package built into it, which can easily create bridged interfaces which will do what you want. In essence, a switch/bridge is simply a networking device to pass packets, and once the outside line becomes packet data at the modem, any Ethernet switch/bridge would easily connect it to your modem if you wanted a switch or bridge between them.  So if you insisted on doing it, then yes, you can configure 3 of your NAS' 5 ports, so that ports 0+1 are bridged without an IP address (crucial otherwise people outside can access it) and used to connect the modem to the router, and port 2 is used for NAS -> LAN with a management IP set on it.

But god knows, I just would never do this.

First off, your router is acting (ideally) as the gateway that secures your local devices against outside. A bridge, even without an IP, is an internal device exposed unprotected. Suppose you misconfigure it, or a FreeNAS update doesn't respect your exact networking config (especially if it had to be set up manually outside the GUI)? Then your NAS and its data might be defenseless, and because it's also on the LAN side of the router via other interfaces, you've just given someone the keys to bypass anything on your router too.

Yes, companies put servers into a DMZ. But they consider what's on them and how that is secured, far more in-depth that you or I could. Even then, they often proxy it (so the outside user actually reaches a proxy or 'bouncer' not the actual server) to improve security and control what goes on.

And for what benefit? To monitor the data? If you want to monitor traffic between them, do it on the router or even get a dirt-cheap switch with port mirroring and stick it between them. Even a 100Mbit 4-8 port managed switch second hand from 10 or 15 years ago on EBay might have that ability. Or you mention pfSense -it has built in logging and packet capture capability on the port connecting it to the modem, if used as a router. Buy an old motherboard and 2GB ram, and do that. But for the love of god, unless you are very sure of yourself and your know-how, do not do what you're describing :)

**Update on mirroring and security**

You have 3 options - monitoring in software (pf or tcpdump on FreeBSD), using a hub, or using a managed/smart switch.

**Using software**, even if you have it bridged, you still need to set up packet mirroring or (for FreeNAS) packet capture unaided in CLI, because this isn't a function in the GUI of FreeNAS even if it exists in the installed OS. So you'll need to have an insight how to do that as well, although it's not hard. You can apparently do port mirroring in FreeBSD, either using the pf.conf option `dup-to`, or using `tcpdump` which is almost always built-in, to tap and duplicate traffic or capture it to file, but I don't know the details. Those would be the ways to do it, though. I wouldn't do it that way due to security issues as stated above.

An old consumer network **hub** (not "switch"!) might be dirt cheap and also work, but I wouldn't go that route due to (addressable) security concerns.  The essence of a hub is it mirrors **all** traffic to **all** ports. If you run cable [modem -> hub -> router], then any device could listen in. But I wouldn't do that for 2 reasons - first is that hubs are more outdated and may be hard to get, but much more important, if it can snoop, it can be detected and perhaps created a weakness that can be hacked/penetrated, because again it's directly linked to the outside and bypasses the router. So I mention this for completeness, not because it's necessarily a good idea!

A **managed switch** would probably be best, because it isolates the traffic from your NAS and it's designed for the job, and small smart switches are very cheap on EBay etc. As I said, even many years old would do the job. But do make sure there is some security config set on it, and check/consider security carefully, for the exact same reason as I gave for the hub. Perhaps mirror ports are designed to be inherently safe, which would be all you need, but I dont know enough to say more about that. You might want to ask separately, about securing a managed switch port connected to the WAN that's used for monitoring the WAN (mirroring traffic) only and isn't shielded by a router or firewall. infosecurity Stack exchange might be helpful on that.

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thank you! Sometimes you have to ask *if* you can do something, even if you know it isn't a good idea.

Comment: I use pfSense and thoroughly recommend it. "Set and forget", expandable, rock solid, actively developed/large community, BSD not Linux based (probably more robust?), and long term/timely sexurity+feature updates. "Just works". Be aware while pfSense doesn't need more than a Pentium 3 or 4 for usual router scales/functions, it will require AES-NI instructions in near future which limits the chip age to Sandy Bridge or later. Also lacks mirroring. Get the cheapest 2ndhand LGA1155/6 CPU+board, a cheap dual port Intel NIC card for 2nd and spare/mirror ports, 2GB ram and a 4GB+ ssd/hdd, and enjoy!

Comment: Ive updated the answer with more info. If you need mirroring, its possible in FreeBSD but why make it hard on yourself and risk config updates wiping out your changes. Get a cheap old managed/smart switch (netgear, cisco, or something else) off EBay - they'll almost all have GUI web control and port mirroring built in (check first!).  And yes I agree, you do :)